# angular-ui-grid 3.0.0-rc.16 Error: gridApi.pagination.on is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

When I follow [tutorial on pagination](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/314_external_pagination)  from angular-ui-grid site.

This code give me an error when page compile:
    gridApi.pagination.on.paginationChanged($scope, function (newPage, pageSize)      {
    paginationOptions.pageNumber = newPage;
    paginationOptions.pageSize = pageSize;
    getPage(newPage -1, pageSize);
});

"Error: gridApi.pagination.on is undefined

I'm using angularjs angular#1.3.11 and ui-grid 3.0.0-rc.16

Comment: I tried with version 3.0.0.-cr.18. Got same results.

Comment: I just tried with angular 1.2.28, got same results.

Comment: I was having all kinds of weird problems until I switched to using ui-grid-unstable.js as opposed to the RC files

Answer (score 14):

You may have not used pagination directive. In the module definition You should define pagination dependency:

```
   var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.grid', 'ui.grid.pagination']);
```

And in the HTML code You should use pagination directive :

```
   <div ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-pagination class="grid"></div>
```

And there is another thing. Check your ui-grid code to existence of this line:[ui-grid code](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid.info/blob/gh-pages/release/3.0.0-RC.18-7774d30/ui-grid.js)

```
     paginationChanged: function (currentPage, pageSize) { }
```

If it does not exist, update your code to latest version of ui-grid

Answer (score 0):

Check if your app has `'ui.grid.pagination'` module (top at file app.js).

Then make sure you had method `onRegisterApi` and get gridApi to your scope.

Next check if there is `'ui-grid-pagination directive'` in your html.

Finally check if you didn't set `'enablePaginationControls'` as false. It shoud be true (default settings).

It must work :)